# mongodb: retrieve the first element of an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Can I make a mongoDB query to retrieve the first element of an array?

Query operators like $elemMatch return array elements that mach some query on their contents. What I want is to query on the array elements index (within the array).

Answer (score 0):

`[$slice][1]` is whats needed. An example using pymongo:

```
db.coll.find_one(searchQuery,{arrayField:{"$slice":1}}
```